# SSH not working on first attempt

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, sshd

We are having an issue with some of our Linux CentOS machines whereby SSH won't connect on the first attempt. If you start a session, wait 5 seconds then restart the session it works fine and continues to work (new connects as well) for around 1hr.

See the images for the wireshark dump and also the SSH config.

```
Host *
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```

[image: Non working SSH]

[image: Working SSH]

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "If you start a session, wait 5 seconds then restart the session". A session is only started when a connection succeeds. Do you mean it fails, then you wait 5 seconds? Also, you should elaborate on "works fine and continues to work (new connects as well) for around 1hr". After 1 hour do things suddenly stop working?

Comment: Sorry, if you try to connect to an SSH server, wait around 5 seconds then stop the connection and try again. This 2nd attempt works fine. No the session doesn't time out but if you disconnect and leave it for around 1 hour it will go back to not being able to connect on the first attempt

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I have the exact same problem and I don't see anything telling in logs on both sides (server and client).

Comment: Ours was an issue with a central firewall, it was not allowing connections to instantly start, I believe it was an IPS / IDS setting.

Answer (score 1):

Typically ssh hangs the first time you connect to something new for a few seconds because the target machine is doing a reverse lookup before it allows you to put in a password/key.

When you say it's failing, do you mean it just hangs perminatly or is there an error of somekind?

Also ssh  with -vvv

ssh computer -vvv

This sill give a very verbose output which could help in figureing out whats wrong.

Comment: It just times out, we then have to reconnect and it connects the first time with no issues.

Comment: `plink.exe -v -ssh 10.110.0.116
Connecting to 10.110.0.116 port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.69
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
Using SSH protocol version 2
Server supports delayed compression; will try this later
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Server unexpectedly closed network connection
FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection`

Comment: ```plink.exe -v -ssh 10.110.0.116
Connecting to 10.110.0.116 port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.69
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
Using SSH protocol version 2
Server supports delayed compression; will try this later
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Server also has ssh-dss host key, but we don't know it
Host key fingerprint is:```